# SQL Server - Date Conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an issue converting dates in SQL Server 2008

The value I am converting looks like this: `30-NOV-44 08.00.00.000000000`

The result I get back looks like this: `2044-11-30 00:00:00.000`

The code I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [USER_ID]
      ,CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING([DATEOFBIRTH],0,11),112) AS ConvertedDate
      ,[DATEOFBIRTH]
  FROM [IAM_Perf].[dbo].[01_Data]
  WHERE DATEOFBIRTH IS NOT NULL
```

Whatever parameter I use on the CONVERT function I get the same format back and a lot of the dates are being converted into the future??!

The results do change when I switch between date and datetime in the first argument of the CONVERT but it makes no impact on the incorrect results.

I am using the substring function because otherwise it will not convert the value and throws this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting date
>   and/or time from character string.

I'm not sure how to combat this, I cannot guaruntee the format will always remain the same either else I would just manually reformat it using some T-SQL

Any one have any Ideas?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since future dates are perfectly valid in SQL Server, the system has to use a heuristic when you only pass it a 2 digit date. I believe the default heuristic is that years 0-49 are in the 21st century, and years 50-99 are in the 20th century. This is, however, [configurable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189577%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

You need to fix this data before it ends up in your database, and should preferably be storing DateOfBirth in a datetime column anyway (rather than as a string).

---

A datetime value doesn't have a format - but if you've converted something into a datetime, and then attempt to display it, it will always be converted back into a string in the same format (unless you explicitly convert it using CONVERT).

Comment: As an addition, you are having to substring your date because the time is not in a valid format with all periods. If you look at the documentation for the CONVERT function you will see that SQL will never convert a date **to** a time with just periods.  In short, SQL will only convert a string to a datetime as long as they are formatted the same way they are in the CONVERT documentation.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, an educational response.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the cutoff year using

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure 'two digit year cutoff', 2011
RECONFIGURE
```

**Note that this is a server-wide setting and can break the queries on other databases**.

Answer (score 0):

2010/10/10_

Convert and then use subtring
select *,substring((convert(varchar(12),hire_date,121)),1,10) from employee

or

This may carry the space next to the date
SUBSTRING([DATEOFBIRTH],0,11),112)

or
Try this same with 10 digit, conversion may happen good
SUBSTRING([DATEOFBIRTH],0,10),112)